# How to disable the new "rename file" behavior in Windows 10 (hitting F2 and cursor left)?

Tags: windows-10

With the latest Windows 10 Update (April 2019) there is a change in Windows Explorer.

**Behavior before:**

1. Mark file and hit F2
2. Click Cursor left one time, and the cursor was here: `testfileˇ.txt`

**New behavior:**

1. Mark file and hit F2
2. Click Cursor left one time, and the cursor is here: `ˇtestfile.txt`

This is against at least a decade of established usability.

How to get back the default behavior?

PS: I wonder why I am the only one noticing such main changes... Windows 10 runs on 400 million devices!

Comment: Have you tested this with other fields in Windows? It may have changed globally, not just for renames. For example, what is the behaviour when selecting the address bar on Windows Explorer? Does this perform the same way, i.e. switch direction? if it does then perhaps its not a rename-only issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Explorer has become much more user-"friendly", and does a very good effort
to protect you against yourself.

To this end it pre-selects the file-name part, while excluding the extension
part, so you will not by mistake change the extension and make the file unusable
by any application that registered that extension.

Unfortunately, pressing <kbd>Left-arrow</kbd> while the text is selected causes
the cursor to be placed to the left of the selection, which is at the beginning
of the file-name.

The solution is simple: Use instead the <kbd>Right-arrow</kbd> key.
This will place the cursor to the right of the selection, which is exactly
where you want it to be.

Comment: `Use instead the Right-arrow key.` #facepalm and #awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

Your experience does not mirror my own:

On Windows 10 1809 (no April update), pressing F2 on a file with an extension highlights the filename with the exception of the .ext.

Pressing the <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> key places the cursor clears the highlight and places the cursor at the beginning of the filename.

Pressing the <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> key places the cursor at the end of the highlighted portion, before the period and extension.

To my knowledge, this has been the default behavior since before Windows 8 at least, though my memory may be incorrect. It has, at least, been the default behavior since the beginning of Windows 10.

This causes me to wonder if there is a settings difference that accounts for this difference behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the answer, but what used to happen after pressing F2, the whole of the filename excluding the dot & extension was highlighted.

You got into the habit of moving cursor left then right to un-highlight and reposition back just before the dot.
I used to do it all the time.

This new 'facility' now appears to un-highlight at the touch of left cursor or right cursor - moving the cursor to the far left on left arrow, and just before the dot on right arrow (as mentioned above music2myear)

I think we will just have to relearn right cursor only from now on!

It was an improvement in Win7 from F2 in WinXP when F2 highlighted all the file name inc dot!

Answer (score -6):

This isn't a big problem, you will have to go to the regedit and there you will have to remap the shortcut buttons. It's not hard but you will have to google for remapping the keys from regedit.

Comment: I am searching for any "rename" shortcut in the Windows registry, but could not find it yet. I also do not know what value I have to set to get back to the default beahavior.

Comment: If the behavior change is as described, this isn’t about remapping shortcuts. And even then, this answer is basically “something something registry, Google it!”, which is not even remotely acceptable.

Comment: At least include in your answer _what_ registry keys need to be modified. If its about Windows, chances are that if they are on this forum to begin with, they've already looked for the relevant registry keys or settings online, and have not found anything; so your answer really isn't helpful at all. At best, it should be a comment, something like "These settings are often found in the registry, have you looked for anything in there?".